# Excel: Find number of unique dates in a row

Tags: excel, date, unique

I have an excel table with a list of dates like this:

```
12.12.2022 20:13
12.12.2022 20:30
12.12.2022 21:06
12.12.2022 21:55
12.12.2022 22:03

14.12.2022 18:24
14.12.2022 19:24

15.12.2022 17:45
15.12.2022 18:55
15.12.2022 20:03

01.01.2023 20:04
```

The list contains values for different years and not all days have values.
I want to get the number of days with existing list entries in 2022.
So for the example list the result should be 3, because the last value es already 2023.

I guess it must work with UNIQUE somehow, but I don't know how.
The date field is formatted like this:
TT.MM.JJJJ hh:mm

The value is: 14.12.2022  19:24:00

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 5):

With O365:

`=LET(ζ,A1:A14,ROWS(UNIQUE(FILTER(INT(ζ),YEAR(ζ)=2022))))`

Comment: Not working with O365 Excel 2211. I doesn't recognize the symbol that is the first variable to LET

Comment: @user3549835 change that symbol to a letter or word you like

Comment: Thank you. It works. Just for info: Why do I need the rows function?

Comment: `ROWS` is one option to count the number of entries returned by `UNIQUE`.

Comment: Is there a way by any chance to modify the function so that a new day starts at 6 AM?

e.g. an entry on 02 JAN 2023 05:00 AM should be accounted as an entry on the 1st of JAN

Comment: @user3549835 Perhaps some new sample data together with expected result would be useful.

Comment: New sample data:

12.12.2022 20:13
12.12.2022 20:30
12.12.2022 21:06
12.12.2022 21:55
13.12.2022 04:00

14.12.2022 18:24
14.12.2022 19:24

15.12.2022 17:45
15.12.2022 18:55
15.12.2022 20:03

01.01.2023 20:04

I search for dates with data in a certain year where  new date is starting at 6 o'clock
For 2022:
The 13.12. value should count into the 12th. So the exptected result would be 3 (12/14/15 DEC)

Thanks!

Comment: Please test `=LET(ζ,A1:A11,ROWS(UNIQUE(FILTER(INT(ζ-TIMEVALUE("06:00")),YEAR(ζ)=2022))))`

Comment: Hi Jos,
it is working except for new year which is accounted as well if there are entries after midnight. Thank you for you help